# How to make `$(document).on` executable when using jQuery in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add [GDPR plugin v2.0.6](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gdpr/) to an old WordPress website which has been maintained by different people for about 7 years. Those people are not in the company I work for now.

When this plugin is installed, I found an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: e(document).on is not a function

in `gdpr-public.js` file when I open the website.

This error disappeared after I change the code from `$(document).on` to `jQuery(document).on`. But modifying the code inside a plugin is not something we are encouraged to do.

The version of WordPress is 4.7. And the version of PHP is `5.4`

According to this [article](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/), it seems that WordPress originally only supports `jQuery(document).on`. People have to add extra code in order to make `$(document).on` to work properly.

I've also tried installing GDPR plugin to a fresh new [WordPress 4.7](https://wordpress.org/wordpress-4.7.zip). But it doesn't show the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e(document).on is not a function

What might cause `$(document).on` fail to execute?

------------------------------ Edit --------------------------------

The WordPress website has a custom theme. It seems that it doesn't use the default jQuery inside the theme. Because I found the following code under `wp-content/themes/customTheme/functions.php`

```
// Load jQuery
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

When I remove this code, different errors occur when visiting the website:

[image]

It looks like it's difficult to handle this legacy website.

Comment: usually, this is just my first line in my custom JS : `jQuery(function($) { ` - then $ works, if jquery is already enqued.

Comment: This https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/ explains why a global $ is not preferred and how to wrap your js code in a closure. Actually the plugin code is correctly wrapped in a closure (https://github.com/trewknowledge/GDPR/blob/master/src/js/public/gdpr-public.js), so the problem is somewhere else. In which exact line the error occurs?

Comment: @EriksKlotins The error happens at line 55 `$(document).on('submit', '.gdpr-privacy-preferences-frm', function(e) {` in gpdr-public.js.

Answer (score -2):

If `console.log(typeof $)` is `undefined` you can try to make it point to jQuery like so:

```
if (!window.$ && window.jQuery) {
    window.$ = window.jQuery;
}
```

or better

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    window.$ = $;
});
```

to make sure jQuery has already been loaded.

Comment: Where should I add this code? I don't think adding it in `gdpr-public.js` is a good idea. Because it's a third-party plugin written by others.

Comment: You are right.
I assume you can already enqueue scripts in your Wordpress theme.
You can also enqueue your custom script the same way.

Maybe use something like ```jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { window.$ = $});``` to jQuery is already loaded.

Comment: see : https://github.com/trewknowledge/GDPR/blob/master/src/js/public/gdpr-public.js The code is wrapped in a closure and uses global jQuery not $. The problem is somewhere else..